# "Not just a XYZ" or "Not only a XYZ"?

Tags: expression-choice

Which expression is preferred? I found in writing the expression

> "Not just a ___."

but maybe it is better to write

> "Not only a ___."

What do you think? Does it even matter? The context is a very large MNC describing their offers. "We offer not just vechiles, but also..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, *"not only"* and *"not just"* are interchangeable. Either choice is fine in your example. Take a look at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72182/difference-between-just-and-only).

*Merriam-Webster* even bundles them together along with *merely*.

> [not just/only/merely](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/not%20just/only/merely): something more than

*Example: It is not just/only/merely a novel; it is a literary classic.*