# what is the difference between the following 2 sentences in their meaning regarding the word 'just'?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, phrase-meaning

1. You have to push this button.
2. You have to *just* push this button.

What role does the word '*just*' play in the sentence above?

Comment: Similarly, it functions as "merely" - that it's as simple as merely pushing this button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of "just", "only" and word-order \[intended meaning\]](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39994/usage-of-just-only-and-word-order-intended-meaning)

Comment: Arguably each of the following sentences has a different sense from the others because of where the word _just_ appears: "Just you have to push this button." "You just have to push this button." You have to just push this button." "You have to push just this button."

Answer (score 1):

*You have to [just push this button].*

The adverb "just" is a focusing modifier here. It's modifying the verb phrase "push this button". It means that all you have to do is push this button, and do nothing else.

Comment: Essentially saying that _'just'_ is used here in the sense of _'only'_, which implies _'directly'_ and _'exactly'_, both of which meanings come down from the Latin root word _'justus'_ (the same root word for _'justice'_).  See: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217321

Comment: The word order sounds odd to me.  I would say  - *You just have to push the button*.  Curiously though, when I use 'only', *only* can go either side of 'have' - *you have only to push the button / you only have to push the button*.

Comment: Arguably, the contrast is between merely pushing the button and say twisting then pushing, but the sentence would usually be understood as being synonymous with (2') You just/merely have to push this button.

Answer (score 1):

*just* is suggesting an exact idea of how to do something.

The Oxford English Dictionary has a definition:

> Exactly, precisely; verily, actually; closely

Without it, it's simply a blunt command to do something.

With it, it's proposing a specific task that will *precisely* accomplish what's needed.

eg

> Kill him! 
>   Just kill him!